# Python: why do I get an error when I import geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I try to import `geopandas` in my `jupyter` notebook.

```
import geopandas as gp
```

and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libkea.1.4.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Below the installed packages

```
conda list

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.0.1            py37h1de35cc_1  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astroid                   2.1.0                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.1              py37h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py37_0  
attrs                     18.2.0           py37h28b3542_0  
babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                      py37_1  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py37_0  
bitarray                  0.8.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blaze                     0.11.3                   py37_0  
bleach                    3.0.2                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.14.4               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     1.0.2                    py37_0  
boost-cpp                 1.68.0            h6f8c590_1000    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h1d22016_1  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h1de35cc_5  
ca-certificates           2018.11.29           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12           h9d4d9ac_1005    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.11.29            py37_1000    conda-forge
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h6174b99_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
click-plugins             1.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               0.6.1                    py37_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.6.6                    py37_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.17.6                   py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-verify              3.1.1                    py37_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0  
cryptography              2.5              py37hdbc3d79_1    conda-forge
curl                      7.63.0            heae2a1f_1000    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.2           py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37h1de35cc_1  
dask                      1.0.0                    py37_0  
dask-core                 1.0.0                    py37_0  
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1  
dbus                      1.13.2               h760590f_1  
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0  
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1  
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
distributed               1.25.1                   py37_0  
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py37_2  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py37h1de35cc_2  
filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0  
fiona                     1.8.4           py37h0e3174d_1002    conda-forge
flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1  
flask-cors                3.0.7                    py37_0  
fontconfig                2.13.1            h1e4e890_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
freexl                    1.0.5             h1de35cc_1002    conda-forge
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0  
gdal                      2.4.0           py37h0e3174d_1002    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
geos                      3.7.1             h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.4.3             hce09ea4_1000    conda-forge
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.3.7            py37h1de35cc_1  
giflib                    5.1.4             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0  
glob2                     0.6                      py37_1  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.9.0           nompi_py37h35dc34b_1102    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13                        0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.4          nompi_h646315f_1105    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.4.1                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144  
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0  
isort                     4.3.4                    py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0  
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0  
jpeg                      9c                h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0  
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0  
kealib                    1.4.10            hf5ed860_1002    conda-forge
keyring                   17.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py37h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.16.2            h24a3359_1000    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37h1de35cc_2  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.63.0            h76de61e_1000    conda-forge
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libdap4                   3.19.1            hae55d67_1000    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20170329         hb402a30_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgdal                   2.4.0             h89caebc_1002    conda-forge
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libkml                    1.3.0             h71ee1b2_1009    conda-forge
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_0  
libnetcdf                 4.6.2             h6b88ef6_1001    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.35               ha441bb4_0  
libpq                     10.6              hbe1e24e_1000    conda-forge
libpysal                  4.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialindex           1.8.5             h0a44026_1003    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            h0cd9627_1026    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.0             hf30b1f0_1003    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.9                hcb84e12_2  
libxml2                   2.9.8                hab757c2_1  
libxslt                   1.1.32               hb819dd2_0  
llvmlite                  0.26.0           py37h8c7ce04_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markupsafe                1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.0.2            py37h54f8f79_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mgwr                      2.0.1                 py37_1000    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.1                      144  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py37hfbe908c_5  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py37h27c97d8_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h27c97d8_0  
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
munch                     2.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py37_1  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.2                      py37_1  
nltk                      3.4                      py37_1  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  5.7.4                    py37_0  
numba                     0.41.0           py37h6440ff4_0  
numexpr                   2.6.8            py37h7413580_0  
numpy                     1.15.4           py37hacdab7b_0  
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37h6575580_0  
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0  
odo                       0.5.1                    py37_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openjpeg                  2.3.0             h3bf0609_1003    conda-forge
openpyxl                  2.5.12                   py37_0  
openssl                   1.0.2p            h1de35cc_1002    conda-forge
packaging                 18.0                     py37_0  
palettable                3.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.4           py37h6440ff4_0  
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             ha5e8f32_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0  
partd                     0.3.9                    py37_0  
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.42                 h378b8a2_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    5.3.0            py37hb68e598_0  
pip                       18.1                     py37_0  
pixman                    0.34.0            h1de35cc_1003    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py37_1  
pluggy                    0.8.0                    py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
poppler                   0.67.0            hf4bf5f7_1002    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
postgresql                10.6              ha1bbaa7_1000    conda-forge
proj4                     5.2.0             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.5.0                    py37_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                    py37_0  
psutil                    5.4.8            py37h1de35cc_0  
psycopg2                  2.7.7            py37hdbc3d79_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.7.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37hd4eaf27_0  
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37hdbc3d79_0  
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0  
pylint                    2.2.2                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.25           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.3.0                    py37_0  
pyproj                    1.9.6           py37h9c430a6_1000    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pysal                     2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.4.4           py37h0af8b44_1004    conda-forge
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.1             h145921a_1000    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.7.5                    py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytz                      2018.7                   py37_0  
pywavelets                1.0.1            py37h1d22016_0  
pyyaml                    3.13             py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py37_0  
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0  
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py37_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0  
rope                      0.11.0                   py37_0  
rtree                     0.8.3                 py37_1000    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.14.1           py37h0a44026_0  
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.1.0            py37h1410ff5_2  
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0  
shapely                   1.6.4           py37h2bcc7ef_1002    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0  
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
spglm                     1.0.6                   py_1000    conda-forge
sphinx                    1.8.2                    py37_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1  
spreg                     1.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.2                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.2.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h1d22016_0  
sympy                     1.3                      py37_0  
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0  
tornado                   5.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
tqdm                      4.28.1           py37h28b3542_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0  
tzcode                    2018g             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0  
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py37h1de35cc_2  
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0  
xerces-c                  3.2.2             h44e365a_1001    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                    py37_0  
xlwings                   0.15.1                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.2.5                h0a44026_1  
zict                      0.1.3                    py37_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

Comment: There is something wrong with one of the dependencies of GDAL (a dependency of geopandas). Can you give a bit more information on how you installed geopandas? Can you show the result of `conda list` ?

Comment: I installed geopandas via `conda`. Then I unistalled it and tried to install it via `pip`. `conda list` is really long. Should I copy and paste?

Comment: Try `conda install libgdal`. It helped me when I installed geopandas last time. Edit: sorry, I see you have it...

Comment: You have a mixture of packages from the default channel and from conda-forge. That can give such problems. I recommend either installing everything from the default channel, or either everything from conda-forge. See also https://conda-forge.org/docs/conda-forge_gotchas.html#using-multiple-channels

Answer (score 0):

I get around this problem by creating a new environment and ensuring my `gdal` install is from the conda-forge channel by setting the `channel_priority` to `strict`:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.7`

`conda activate myenv`

`conda config --set channel_priority strict`

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal poppler pyproj`

Perhaps installing `poppler` and `pyproj` in the same command is extraneous, but I have had problems with them as well. A clean `GDAL` install is priceless for all the nice new tools like `geopandas`, `fiona`, and `rasterio`!